# how do i add an event when jquery autocomplete results are complete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Jquery UI Autocomplete plugin this way

```
 $("#home_search_top").autocomplete({
                source: "/theme/site_theme/search.php",
                minLength: 2,
                parse: function() {
                    console.log("hello");
                return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
                    $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
                }
            });

            $("#home_search_top").autocomplete({
                source: "/theme/site_theme/search.php",
                minLength: 2,
                loadingClass : "res-search"
            });
```

how do i show or hide someDiv when parsing is complete ?

Comment: Look through the API for the event you want to hook into: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#events

Comment: Any reason you aren't able to call the callback function from inside the parse() handler itself?

Comment: i am new to jquery. please show me an example, it would be very helpfull

Comment: the demos have "View Source". You are likely to find exactly what you want there....not sure what you mean by "parsing complete'

Comment: What do you mean by "when parsing is complete"? There's no `parse:` option in the autocomplete widget.

Comment: i mean when resutls from the source files a completly received

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `response` event (assuming you're using jQueryUI 1.9). From the documentation:

> Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful
>   for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom source
>   option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a
>   search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are
>   no results or the Autocomplete is disabled.

You should tap into this event and hide `#someDiv`:

```
 $("#home_search_top").autocomplete({
     source: "/theme/site_theme/search.php",
     minLength: 2,
     select: function(event, ui) {
         $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
         $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);
     },
     response: function () {
         $("#someDiv").hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#state_id').val(ui.item.id);
        $('#abbrev').val(ui.item.abbrev);

        // hide div:
        $("#MyDiv").hide();
    }
```